# API Magento 2.4.5. The consumer isn't authorized to access %resources Endpoint Magento_Customer

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.5

The consumer isn't authorized to access %resources.

```
{
    "message": "The consumer isn't authorized to access %resources.",
    "parameters": {
        "resources": "Magento_Customer::customer"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if API user role have appropriate permission to access **Magento_Customer** resource.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change configuration **Yes** in: Allow OAuth Access Tokens to be used as standalone Bearer tokens

- Go to: Admin / Stores / SERVICES / Oauth / Allow OAuth Access Tokens
  to be used as standalone Bearer tokens / Yes
- Click in Save Config
- Cache Management: Flush Magento Cache
  [image]